# Handling multiple errors from thread workers

Tags: java, exception

I spawn worker threads to do job:

```
        List<Future<WorkerInfo>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfUsers; i++) {
            Future<WorkerInfo> future = threadExecutor.submit(() -> runLoad(arguments));
            futures.add(future);
        }
```

Now `runLoad(..)` function returns the state of the worker:

```
private WorkerInfo runLoad(int load,...) {
    // start of the load
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Thread.currentThread().setName("LoadWorker with load: " + load);
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < load; i++) {
            // do something
        }

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        return WorkerInfo .success(load, end);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        return new WorkerInfo (load, end, e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

The WorkerInfo class is simple class holding data:

```
public class WorkerInfo {
    private final int load;
    private final long time;
    private final String message;
    private final Throwable error;

    public WorkerInfo (int load, long time, String message, Throwable error) {
        this.load = load;
        this.time = time;
        this.message = message;
        this.error = error;
    }

    public static WorkerInfo success(int load, long end) {
        return new WorkerInfo(load,end,"",null);
    }

    public boolean hasError(){
        return error != null;
    }

    public int getLoad() {
        return load;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public Throwable getError() {
        return error;
    }
}
```

Now i want to check if there was any error after the execution has finnished.

```
private void checkError(List<Future<WorkerInfo>> futures) {
    List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Future<WorkerInfo > future : futures) {
        WorkerInfo  workerInfo = unpackFuture(future);
        if (workerInfo .hasError()) {
            String message = workerInfo .getMessage();
            errors.add(message);
        }
    }

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      // what to throw here?
    }
}
```

WHat is the best practice when multiple worker throw error? Lets say i am running 6 workers and 4 of them end with error. What error message should i throw then? What is the best way to aggregate the error messages into one? Or how to handle this?

Thanks for help!

Comment: The question might be opinion-based. --- My opinion is that we should create some `MultipleException`-class, wrapping all the exceptions and then throw this `MultipleException`.

Comment: @Turing85 Does java even support MultipleException? When you extend RunTimeException there is no constructor for multiple causes or error messages

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. You would have to write the class by yourself and of course provide fitting constructors. `RuntimeException` has no automatic support to pass along multiple causes. Hence, if we were to print the custom `MultipleException`, the stack trace would always show to the point where the `MultitpleException` was created.